# Install python in wine - configuring paths from winetricks?

Tags: wine, python, winetricks

I am trying to install Python 2.6 on WINE 1.5 in Ubuntu 12.04.  (Yes, I need the WINE version, not the native Ubuntu version).

I have WINE 1.5 running just fine.  I do

```
winetricks python26
```

Which seems to install python26 just fine, but in the `~/.local/share/wineprefixes/python26/` directory, rather than in `.wine/c_drive/...`

When I try `wine python` I'm told

```
wine: cannot find L"C:\\windows\\system32\\python.exe"
```

How do I tell wine to look in the location where winetricks put this file?  Presumably there is a way to set python path?

**My Attempts**

I did try copying the `python.exe` from the `~/.local/share/wineprefixes/python26/` directory into the `.wine/drive_c/system32` directory, but then simply get an error about a missing DLL:

```
err:module:import_dll Library python26.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\windows\\system32\\python.exe") not found
err:module:LdrInitializeThunk Main exe initialization for L"C:\\windows\\system32\\python.exe" failed, status c0000135
```

but that doesn't seem the right way to do this anyhow.

I also tried running `winecfg` and adding an application, and pointing it to the python.exe file in the `~/.local/share/wineprefixes/python26/` directory, but I get the same

```
wine: cannot find L"C:\\windows\\system32\\python.exe"
```

error.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run `wine python`, *wine* will assume that you are running it from the default prefix in `~/.wine`.

To make it use another prefix, in your case you need to running with the *WINEPREFIX* option as such:

```
WINEPREFIX=/path/to/wineprefix wine executable
```

It should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks, but I still get the error `err:module:import_dll Library python26.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\windows\\system32\\python.exe") not found` when I use that.  What did I miss?

Comment: Working on it, I will let you know as soon as I have this on a vbox running.

Comment: I know this is an old post. I think you were getting the missing DLL message because you had copied the python.exe into the system32 directory so wine is trying to execute python from the wrong place.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use win32_addpath.py in C:\Python26\Tools\Scripts\:

1. Open cmd by wine

   wine cmd
2. change directory to Python26 folder

   cd /home//.wine/drive_c/Python26/
3. run the script

   python.exe Tools/Scripts/win32_addpath.py
   Hope it gonna hep.